# How to find and replace multiple text lines with corrosponding text?

Tags: text-editor

I have number of files and a set of find and replace text combinations.

For example, I have a set of find text and replace text like this,

- find - "margin" replace with "new_margin"
- find - "color" replace with "color_primary"
- find - "xxx" replace with "zzzz"
- find - "rre" replace with "768"

I have nearly 100 of such combinations, i need to find all "find texts" and replace it with corresponding replace text.

How can I do this easily?

Is there any tool to do this?

Comment: Could you please provide the input, I mean your find/replace sets. Are they saved in a file or how ?!

Answer (score 1):

to substitute the text inside the files in a single shot you can use sed:

```
sed -i -e 's@margin@new_margin' -e 's@color@color_primary@' -e 's@xxx@zzz@' -e '@rre@768@' /path/to/files/*
```

-i option say to sed to perform modification in file without print

-e say to sed have more string to be find and substituted

s@ says the '@' is the separator for string_to_find and replacement_string

the latest is the path where the file are, if they are all in one location you can perform this command once.

**!!!Execute a backup of your file ALWAYS before make modification with sed in file directly!!!**

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @steeldriver which says in the comment to not modify the source file with sed adding a suffix to the -i options

> -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]

I.E.

```
sed -i_edited 's@margin@new_margin' /path/to/files/examplefile
```

will result with a new file modified called `examplefile_edited`

Comment: They could make a backup *automatically* by providing a suffix argument to the `-i` option

Comment: Upvoted and upflagged all around for backup suggestions. Most answers never suggest that.